# Account vs Block in Blockchain Solana

Tags: blockchain, block, account, solana, solana-transaction-instruction

What is the difference between an Account and a Block in Solana Blockchain technology?

As per solana docs,

**Block**: A contiguous set of entries on the ledger covered by a vote. A leader produces at most one block per slot.

**Account**: A record in the Solana ledger that either holds data or is an executable program.

From the definitions, it seems like they both are the same which becomes part of the ledger as an individual transaction. Is it like this or something other concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "ledger" is unfortunately overloaded in Solana, since it refers to both transactions and records that hold data.  Maybe this will clarify a bit more:

- A block is a set of transactions that have been executed (success or failure)
- An account is like a file on an operating system. Transactions read / modify accounts based on the behavior of programs / smart contracts